# Callback function within map

Tags: javascript, cordova, reactjs

I'm new to Reactjs and making a directory browsing application with Cordova and Reactjs.

Currently I get the error `this.props.onClick is not a function`, I figured out that `this.props.onClick` is undefined. Check my code below:

```
var RepositoryList = React.createClass({
    //updating the list from a child folder entry
    updateListFromChild:function(childFolder){ 
        console.log("in parent update");
    },    
    render:function(){
        console.log(this.updateListFromChild); //function()
        var itemsInRepo = this.props.items.map(function(entry){
            console.log("in map: " + this.updateListFromChild); //undefined
            return (
                <RepositoryEntry repositoryItem={entry} 
                                 folderOnClick={this.updateListFromChild} />
            );
        });
        return (
            <ul className="table-view">
                {itemsInRepo}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

The property `folderOnClick` is undefined. But I don't know how to solve this problem. Can someone point this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general - [this is the "dynamic this" issue in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).

However, since you're using ReactJS with JSX, your code has support for ES6 arrow functions in the transform anyway:

```
var itemsInRepo = this.props.items.map(entry => (                
   <RepositoryEntry repositoryItem={entry} folderOnClick={this.updateListFromChild} />
));
```

You can see the syntax on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

We can proceed with this way also. Here is the code snippet:

```
var itemsInRepo = this.props.items.map( 
        function(entry){                
            return(
             <RepositoryEntry 
               repositoryItem={entry} 
               folderOnClick={this.updateListFromChild} 
        />);
```